# Credentials in a request body over Https

Tags: security, post, get, passwords, burp

Hey so am new to pentesting and I learnt that using https makes the traffic encrypted so hackers cannot decipher credentials passed in a body for example in a login page or read the traffic properly. So I was practicing with both GET and POST requests for a login page app over https and in both the credentials are present in the request body when I intercept them using burpsuite. In GET the params are available in the URL and in POST they are present in the body. Can someone explain then how can the privacy of credentials be maintained if they are present in plaintext in the request body. Won't everyone be able to read them??

Testing:

1. Submitted credentials through a login page application over Https.
2. Passed them through both GET and POST methods.

Result:
Able to see creds in both types of calls in the request body.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a [security.se] question, not a programming question. Undoubtedly your burpsuite has access to the plaintext **within** the HTTP request. HTTPS is HTTP over TLS. So if you actually have HTTPS (and not the NULL cipher suite) then *all* HTTP traffic is encrypted, period.

Comment: Commonly you can also setup suites like that as a proxy. In that case burpsuite would offer you its certificate instead of the one offered by the server.

Comment: @maartenbodewes then the websites like gmail and everything using a login page have the creds in the body and if someone intercepts or picks that up using burp they can get the login details like that, is that acceptable??

Comment: Well, it only works if you would first accept the certificate with `*.google.com` in it of course. Normally those will not be signed by just any CA. So you'd have to use your own and place a certificate in the root store of the browser (a self signed root or server certificate).

Answer (score 0):

Burpsuite sees them because it runs as a proxy for the browser. Over HTTPS both GET and POST parameters are encrypted once they leave the browser.

Note that the URL as such doesn’t leave the browser (or, more generally, user agent). A connection is made using the hostname and port (those will still be visible to a man-in-the-middle) but the GET parameters are sent using HTTPS once the connection is established.

The reason people say not to pass sensitive information in GET requests is because the URL may end up in log files, browser history, seen over people’s shoulders, etc. Also GET requests can be cached.